# How can I determine which half of an elliptical path a point is currently on?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, physics, kinematics

Here is a static frame from an atom animation I'm working on in JavaScript, modelled off [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg/220px-Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png).

[image]

Here is the code used to determine the position of an electron in its orbit based on time:

```
// Get position along elliptical path.
var x = Math.cos( this.timer.delta() * this.speed ) * ( this.pathWidth / 2 );
var y = Math.sin( this.timer.delta() * this.speed ) * ( this.pathHeight / 2 );
```

What I'd like to do is place the electron **above** the nucleus when on the orange part of the path, and **below** the nucleus during the green segment.

When `this.timer.delta() == 0`, the electron is at the extreme-right end, and then proceeds to travel counter-clockwise.

I'm looking for help with the following two things:

1) Finding the point in time in which the electron will be at the far left of its orbit.

2) Determining which half of the path an electron is currently on for any given time.

Ideally, the solutions should work regardless of the value of `this.speed` (which is number multiplier for speeding up or slowing down the animation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the angle - and the angle is this part in your expression:

```
this.timer.delta() * this.speed
```

So you can simply determine whether the angle is between zero and PI - and if it is - the nucleus is "in front".

Of course simply checking whether y is non-negative does the same trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer was simpler than what I was expecting, but it was exactly what I needed. :)